# Making Divs hidden by default in Javascript

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hide

Just a quick one hopefully, my Javascript knowledge is poor thought and I can't work this one out.

I have some Javascript code that makes contact expand when a link is clicked, however at present the contact is visible by default, and I want it to be hidden until the link is clicked, any ideas?

The jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/p7Ebh/

js

```
$("a.box-toggle").on('click', function () {
    $('div.box-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
});
```

html

```
<section class="box2">
<header class="box-head">
    <div class="box-title fr"> <span class="box-icon"></span>

            <h3 class="box-title-text">Title Title</h3>

    </div>  <a class="box-toggle fl active" href="#">A</a>

</header>
<div class="box-content active">
    <img src="http://carryingthegun.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/personal_trollface_hd.png" alt="" width="200" height="200" />Content or collapsing data goes here</div>
</section>
```

css

```
.widget-toggle {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 9px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    background: url(../img/sidebar-arrows.png) no-repeat 0 -18px;
}
.widget-toggle.active {
    background: url(../img/sidebar-arrows.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not hide it with css?

Answer (score 3):

using `.hide()` you can make invisible the div content when you load the page, and after appear only when the user click on the link.
try this:

```
    $('div.box-content').hide();    
    $("a.box-toggle").on('click', function () {
        $('div.box-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

[**DEMO1**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Ebh/1/)

Another solution is tou use only CSS without using `.hide()` in jQuery like this:

```
.box-content{
    display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Ebh/5/)

Comment: +1 for CSS solution. The pages' styles are rendered far before the DOM is ready, and WAY before jQuery has been loaded. If the user has a slow internet connection, it's likely they will actually see the element before it is hidden through jQuery.

Comment: yes I prefer to use css in this case too :) @NateKibler

Answer (score 1):

you could also add `display:none` in the `.box-content` css:

```
.box-content{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `.hide()` at document.ready??

```
$('div.box-content').hide();    
$("a.box-toggle").on('click', function () {
        $('div.box-content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use *.hide()* in jquery

```
 $(".box-content ").hide();
```